# Reading from a text file with spaces and then putting into arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, bresenham

I have spent the last week trying to figure out how to make this stupid code work. I have managed to get everything to work except for reading from my text file. It can read an individual integer on a line, but when given a line with multiple integers separated by spaces, it freaks out. Now I've gone and tried to fix it and the code won't even compile anymore. Only one line is causing problems.
I'm not good at coding, so I don't know where to begin. Yes, I've looked this up online. Yes, I've checked the forums. Yes, I have tried multiple different methods to make this work....
How do I fix this?? :(

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// the above line is in a different method in the same class, but it's relevant here


File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Jocelynn\\Desktop\\input.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try
    {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String text = null;


        while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            // I want the following line to read "218 150 500 330", and to store each individual integer into the list. I don't know why it won't work :(
            list.add(Integer.parseInt(src.next().trim()));
        }
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    try
    {
   reader.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }


//print out the list
System.out.println(list);
```

Thank you for the help! I'm sure that I'm just missing something really simple...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`Scanner(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.lang.String%29) like

```
while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text);
    while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        list.add(scanner.nextInt());
    }
}
```

Of course, your entire method could be simplified by using a [`try-with-resources` Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and the [`diamond operator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html) and just [`Scanner(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File%29) like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Jocelynn\\Desktop\\input.txt");

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);) {
        while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            list.add(scanner.nextInt());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // print out the list
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this inside the **while** loop

```
String[] individualArray = text.split(" ");//note space
for(String individual:individualArray){
    yourList.add(individual);//You need to parse it to integer here as you have already done
}
```

In the above code, **individualArray** will contain each individual integers that are `separated by space`. And inside the **for loop** each string needs to be parsed to integer and then added to your list

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Jocelynn\\Desktop\\input.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try
        {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String text = null;

            while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                // you need only this for loop in you code.
                for (String value : text.split(" ")) {  // get list of integer
                     if(!value.equals(""))             // ignore space                      
                     list.add(Integer.parseInt(value));  // add to list
                }

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try
        {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // print out the list
        System.out.println(list);

    }
```